# App Transport Security doesn't exclude the specified exception subdomain

Tags: ios, http, https, app-transport-security

Yesterday my app got rejected because of the ATS "incompatibility", but I configured the app's .Plist file as mentioned in many questions here, in SO. By that I mean I added the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>sub.domain.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

if I remove this block of code, my app gets approved, but there is a server, that the app connects, which is on HTTP (and I don't have control to change it to HTTPS) and the data is not visible on the app.
Any ideas, please?

Comment: What exactly was the text of Apple's rejection?

Comment: @Paulw11 , they cannot open the app at all, because it tries to connect asap.

Comment: I don't understand your question then. Is the problem that your app tried to connect to a HTTP server that isn't in your ATS exclusion?  If so, then add it.

Comment: You didn't actually include "sub.domain.com" as a key in your `NSExceptionDomains`, did you? Did you just put that in there for the example?  If that is the exact contents of your actual Info.plist, you'll need to change the "sub.domain.com" to the actual domain of the server you are contacting.